# Can we have two different authentication for same application IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I'm creating WEB-API application which had auto generated document feature work as MVC.  And general end points as API controllers, initially API end points works fine with tokens authentications. But after I'm trying to do MVC controllers authenticated using a cookie mode, it working as expected but API controllers fails "Authorization has been denied".

In Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            var auth = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthAuthority"];

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<String, String>();

            var tokenOptions = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions();
            tokenOptions.Authority = auth;
            tokenOptions.PreserveAccessToken = true;

            //adding for Outh2 authentication

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44300/",
                ClientId = "mvc_Doc",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:64741/Help",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                Scope = "openid profile",

            });

            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(tokenOptions);

            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

How would I handle this?

Comment: Don't mix UI endpoints and API endpoints in the same app -- they have different security requirements.

Comment: yes @BrockAllen it's true, but this is slightly  different , this is not UI end point but feature of WEB-API (which) auto generate the Documentation based on API end point which we willing to keep .

Comment: Ok, so if your APIs are doing security and you want to use the cookie you have in the UI then also make sure you have an anti-xsrf token to prevent xsrf attacks on the API.

Comment: finally found the way to do that , simply add new client in IdentityServer with   Flow = Flows.Hybrid,